# Flutter TextFIeld is not centered when height is less than 50

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text field inside a container which I'm trying to center using Center widget. I notice that it works when the height is greater than 50 but doesn't work when less than 50, say 40.

Can someone help me explain this behaviour?

Below is the code for

```
Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 100,
                height: 40,
                child: Center(
                  child: TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    controller: TextEditingController(text: 'IJ'),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                  ),
                ))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is likely because of the  `EdgeInsets scrollPadding: constEdgeInsets.all(20.0),` set as default in the Textfield implementation. This would imply that the minimum textfield height in flutter is more than 40px.

Source: [Text-field](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

Comment: Would changing scrollPadding correct this? Also, I have this weird situation when some of my TextFields(in the lower row) have their bottom cut off slightly when wrapped in a Wrap widget.

Comment: Scroll Padding has probably no role to play in this behaviour of TextField.